# Testing form tampering in a Symfony 2 multi tenant application

Tags: forms, symfony, security, symfony-forms

In my project an `User` can create a `Customer` and assigning it zero or more `Tag`. These entities have a relation with `User` of course. This is done by a form that has a `tag` field of [entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), filtered by current logged user:

```
$user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

$builder
    ->add('tags', 'meta_selector', array(
        'label'         => 'Tag',
        'class'         => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Tag',
        'property'      => 'select_label',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($user) {
            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('t');

            return $qb
                ->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.user_id', ':user')
                ->orderBy('t.name')
                ->setParameter('user', $user);
        }
    ))
;
```

And this is working fine. Looking at a generated HTML tags are rendered as checkboxes:

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="customer[tags][2]"
            id="customer_tags_2"> A Tag
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="customer[tags][3]" 
            id="customer_tags_3"> Another Tag
    </label>
</div>
```

I'd like to investigate further about form tampering. In particular making a POST request from a trusted user adding `customer%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D=1`, that is a tag with `id` equal to 1 which exists but it has been created by another user. Attacker user is creating an customer with a tag created by another user:

```
POST http://localhost/Symfony2/web/app_dev.php/app/customers/new HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/Symfony2/web/app_dev.php/app/customers/new
Cookie: PHPSESSID=3avu1a2a1eufthr5tdftuhrnn7; hl=it
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 276

customer%5Bfirst%5D=fake&customer%5Blast%5D=fake&customer%5Bgender%5D=m&customer%5Bbirthday%5D=&customer%5Bemail%5D=&customer%5Bmobile%5D=&customer%5Baddress%5D=&customer%5Bcountry%5D=IT&customer%5Btags%5D%5B1%5D=1&customer%5B_token%5D=455783fa2f866677669c9034a90554b9f75d68b4
```

.. and seems there is some sort of control that prevents this. Result is `200 OK` (should be a `302` in case of success) without any error and form is rendered again. Of course  entity is not persisted.

Actual question is: how Symfony 2 protect from this kind of form "tampering" attacks? A possible explanation is the it checks that submitted tags exist inside the collection returned by the form builder. But a reference is needed...

**EDIT**: even disabling CSRF protection the result is the same. By the way i was passing a valid token and CSRF is intended to protect from other types of attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question can be explained quite easily. Every choice field (and the entity type is a specialization of the choice type) has a list of choices. For each choice, the field is aware about

- the model representation ("choice") of the choice (e.g. a `Tag` instance)
- the view representation ("value") of the choice (e.g. the ID)
- the label used in the view (e.g. a property of `Tag`)

When you submit the form, the choice field looks in this list which model representation matches the submitted view representation. If none can be found, the field remains unassigned.

The code for this logic can be found in the class [ChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php) and its descendants, in your case [EntityChoiceList](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/EntityChoiceList.php). Upon submission, the method [getChoicesForValues()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/EntityChoiceList.php#L194) is executed which does the lookup and is optimized for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Wild  guess: CSRF protection is enabled and you do not render the errors.

Comment: AFAIK CSRF has nothing to do with what i'm talking, that is is useless in my case as you can see: i'm sending the valid token along with POST data...

Comment: So when you disable it in the config.yml the result ist the same?

Comment: I've tested without form csrf protection and it does the same. It's returning 200 OK with the form, without errors. Is this some internal mechanism by Sf2 that prevents attacks like this? Maybe it's going to check if tag with id = 1 is in the collection returned by the builder?